# Find previous <a> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="/user/SOMEUSERNAME">SOMEUSERNAME</a>
<div class="col s9">
  <p id="p_50">Some message</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span class="forumtools">
    <strong>
      <a onclick="quote(\'p#p_50\')">Quote</a>
    </strong>
  <span class="right">Written SOMEDATE</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

JQuery/JS:

```
function quote(post) { $(post).text(); }
```

This works to fetch the posts message, but how do I go about finding the Username?

I have tried using `$(post).prev('a').text();`, and `$(post).parent().prev('a').text();`, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You can use https://api.jquery.com/prev/ to get the previous element.

Comment: For your issue you can add a data-username on the a element with the username.

Comment: @Oddadmix OP posted that they have tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: What is `post`?

Comment: `post` is the p_POSTID (example p_50)

Comment: Why can't you give the `a` an id? and get it that way?

Comment: Given the specific structure:  `$(post).parent().prev().text()`  not sure why yours didn't work - can you set it up as a snippet (or fiddle)?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid An ID is usually a poor option. There are probably multiple posts per page and multiple a tags. Maybe a generated id that matches the post like `p_50_userlink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without jQuery. If possible, change the html and pass the current link to the function, like this:

```
<a onclick="quote(\'p#p_50\', this)">Quote</a>
```

Then you can just search through all links:

```
function quote(str, currentLink) {
  var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // get all links in document
  var index = allLinks.indexOf(currentLink);
  if (index > 0) {
    var prevLink = allLinks[index-1];
    console.log(prevLink); // log it to browser console
  } else { 
    console.log("there is no previous link"); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the DOM structure, it should work with `$(post).parent().prev().text()`.

Alternative way, how about you wrap all of them with `<div>`, like this: XD

```
<div id="message1">
<a href="/user/SOMEUSERNAME">SOMEUSERNAME</a>
<div class="col s9">
  <p id="p_50">Some message</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span class="forumtools">
    <strong>
      <a onclick="quote(\'#message1\')">Quote</a> //change to wrapper id
    </strong>
  <span class="right">Written SOMEDATE</span>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

then to get the post text: `$(post).find('#p_50').text();`

to get the username: `$(post).find('a:first').text();`

Comment: Just be sure to tell the OP that a query like `$(post).parent().prev().text().` is very brittle and the OP should better structure the HTML instead of writing code that will change with even a minor change in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample HTML, if you're at `p`, just go to parent element and get the closest `a` and you should be fine:

```
function quote(post) {
    var post = $(post).text(); 
    var user = $(post).parent().closest('a').text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using parent() and then previous()

```
var ancortext = $(post).parent().prev().text();
```

A function example below.

```
function username(post) { 

     return $(post).parent().prev().text(); 
}
```

Note: This smells to me, your code is very much tied into the structure of the HTML this way. If you alter the HTML, chances are your javascript will break.

I have copied your code into my own HTML document, and confirmed that the jquery method calls above output the desired result. If you are not, then something is different with your source HTML and the source that you posted, or your jquery functions differ from the ones stated in this answer :)

Comment: That's because your JS fiddle was wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/wrco905a/10/

Answer (score 0):

your onclick attribute is wrong,because onclick accept javascript,so the value could be support js,then onclick="`quote('p#p50')`".

```js
function quote(post) {
      var subject = $(post).text();
      var user=$(post).parent().prev('a').text();
      console.log('posted '+subject+' by '+user);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/user/SOMEUSERNAME">SOMEUSERNAME</a>
<div class="col s9">
    <p id="p_50">Some message</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="forumtools">
    <strong>
      <a onclick="quote('p#p_50')">Quote</a>
    </strong>
  <span class="right">Written SOMEDATE</span>
  </span>
</div>
```